# C# obtener datos relacionados de una clase

Tags: c#, entity-framework, clase, relaciones

Buen día, señores.
Tengo días buscando, pero no he podido dar con la respuesta.
Esto que busco hacer en C# si se puede hacer en Java, alguna ves lo vi en codigo pero al no saber el termino de esta practica no he podido dar con documentación que me ayude para C#.

Por ejemplo, tengo mi clase **Paciente**

```
public class paciente
{
    public int id_paciente {get; set;}
    public string nombre {get; set;}
    public int id_ciudad {get; set;}
    public int id_status {get; set;}
}
```

Si yo quisiera hacer una consulta a **paciente** en Linq
sería algo así:

```
conection.paciente.ToList();
```

Y me devolvería un Json algo así:

```
{
   id_pasiente: 1,
   nombre: "Daniel",
   id_ciudad: 1,
   id_status: 1,
}
```

Ahora, lo que quiero hacer es crear mi clase **Paciente** de la siguiente forma:

```
public class paciente
    {
        public int id_paciente {get; set;}
        public string nombre {get; set;}
        public Ciudad ciudad {get; set;}
        public Status status {get; set;}
    }
```

Y una vez agregados las clases **Status** y **Ciudad**, lanzar el mismo query:

```
conection.paciente.ToList();
```

Para recibir **Paciente** y todos los objetos relacionados con esta tabla, algo así:

```
{
       id_pasiente: 1,
       nombre: "Daniel",
       ciudad: {
          id_ciudad: 1,
          nombre: Mazatlan
       },
       status: {
          id_status: 1,
          nombre: activo
       }
    }
```

Y así obtener todos los subobjetos relacionados en todas las clases que tenga relacionadas con alguna otra.

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes de incluir propiedades para identificar la ciudad y status (string ciudadId | string statusId) y propiedades de navegación (Ciudad ciudad | Status status), la cual te va a permitir traer la información de dicha ciudad o status.

```
public class paciente
{
    public int id_paciente {get; set;}
    public string nombre {get; set;}
    
    public string ciudadId {get; set;}
    public Ciudad ciudad {get; set;}

    public string statusId {get; set;}
    public Status status {get; set;}
}
```

Luego debes incluir la propiedad de navegación para traer la data relacionada

```
conection.paciente
  .Include(pacienteDB => pacienteDB.ciudad)
  .Include(pacienteDB => pacienteDB.status )
  .ToList();
```

Revisa estos links que te pueden servir:

[Relaciones: EF Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

[Carga de datos relacionados](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager)

Comment: Muchas gracias, WilsonPT.
Esto es justo lo que queria hacer.